Horror film with a parasite
This is a long shot, but I'm looking for the name about a film that starts out with a bike crash. The woman survives, but has a parasite that comes out of her stomach and attacks another woman in a shower room: her stomach opens up, and teeth come out and kill the woman by the teeth and parasite coming out. I'm sure it's from the 70 or 80s.

English? B&W? Color? Anything else you can remember about the film?

Sound rather Cronenbergian. It's been ages since I saw Rabid or Shivers.

Definitely sounds like Rabid, as mentioned by Meat Trademark:
Marilyn Chambers plays a woman who, after being injured in a motorcycle accident and undergoing a surgical operation, develops an orifice under one of her armpits. The orifice hides a phallic stinger that she uses to feed on people's blood. Soon, those she feeds upon become infected, whose bite spreads the disease and soon causes massive chaos starting with Quebec and ending up in Montreal.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabid_(film)

It's been a million years since I've seen it, but it sounds a bit like Demi Moore's first movie Parasite (1982).  I vaguely recall a scene in a shower where a parasite comes out of a body and attacks someone.

I was thinking of that movie too, but it's got no bike crash, and no shower scene. You can watch it on YouTube if you want to confirm.

No this a colour film

Yes thanks guys the film is rabid
